# How can I select tables with more than or less than a certain number of rows?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I want to identify all tables with more than 6 rows, as well as all tables with 6 or fewer rows.

About the best I can come up with is to loop over the rows for each table and count them, but there must be a more elegant solution. What can I do other than looping and counting to find these tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) method to filter out only the tables that match your criteria. In your case you could select all rows within the table and check the length. Something like this:

```
// Get tables with more than six rows
$("table").filter(function (){
   return $("tr", this).length > 6;
});
```

[**Working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/9Z2Ue/1/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**`jQuery.filter`**](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) for this:

```
$("table").filter(function(){
    return $(this).find("tr").length > 6;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for .filter()

```
$('table').filter(function(index) {
    return $('tr', this).length > 6;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a technique that uses the [`:gt`](http://api.jquery.com/gt) (greater-than) selector to count rows for you:

```
$bigtable = $('table').find('tr:gt(5)').closest('table'); // :gt is zero-indexed
```

After that, you can use [`.not()`](http://api.jquery.not) to get all the tables with six rows or less:

```
$smtable = $('table').not($bigtable);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/44YEf/

Comment: This doesn't address how to find tables with _6 or less_ rows also.

Comment: Strictly speaking, neither do any of the other answers. Updated.

Comment: True, they don't, but translating from the example shown in the others is much more obvious (to me), since it only takes a symbol flip.